# splice selected items from list of dictionary in angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 let listOfDict = [
 {'num':1},
 {'num':2},
 {'num':3},
 {'num':4},
 {'num':5} ]
```

i want to know position and splice 3 and 4 from above list of dictionary items 3 and 4 places might be changing so find index and remove values
in angular typescript

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. You want to get array of dictionaries that contain values 3 and 4? How is position important?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the index, you can splice elements using the [`Array.splice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
let listOfDict = [
 {'num':1},
 {'num':2},
 {'num':3},
 {'num':4},
 {'num':5}
]

listOfDict.splice(3, 2) // Index 3, size 2
```

If you are referring to the values of each object, you can find the indexes first. In doing this we will be creating a new array by filtering out all the values we do not want.

```js
function spliceByValue(array, values) {
  return array.filter(v => {
    return !values.includes(v.num)
  })
}

let listOfDict = [
 {'num':1},
 {'num':2},
 {'num':3},
 {'num':4},
 {'num':5}
]
listOfDict = spliceByValue(listOfDict, [3, 4])
```

Comment: not specific about position it might change every time

Comment: Then the second example, which uses `spliceByValue` should work for your purposes